# modal window not poping up in ie and Nivo Image Slider image not working after uploaded

Tags: html, modal-dialog, nivo-slider

First question:  I have set up a page to use modal windows to pop up a brief description about the waterpark attraction and a nivo image slider that contains a few shots of each attraction.  I can not figure out why the window will not pop up in ie.  The modal window works in every other browser that I have tested???

**In ie none of my buttons on this particular page are able to be clicked?**

Second Question:  When I test my nivo slider locally everything works fine.  However, once I upload everything the slider doesn't work.  I have made sure that all my scripts, css, images, and pages have been uploaded.  I'm stumped.

I am by no means a professional at this so any help with this would be VERY appreciated.

The link to the page is http://splashwaywaterpark.com/attraction

Comment: 1. `scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js` doesn't exist on server. 2. See to that there is no conflict as you are using mootools as well as jQuery.

Comment: I tried to add it just now and received a message that said: scripts:jquery-1.9.0.min.js - error occurred - An FTP error occurred - cannot put jquery-1.9.0.min.js.  Access denied.  The file may not exist, or there could be a permission problem.

Comment: Oh you may not have the permission to do it then. Try linking to a CDN. Add this line `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I removed mootools and the nivo slider still is not working.  I am not actually using those scripts on this particular page.

Comment: nivo slider is not working coz you don't have jQuery. Add the snippet I gave above before all files. It should work.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  The slider is working!  I still can not click any button when using ie.

Comment: Check my answer for IE fix.

Answer (score 0):

Call jQuery before all files so jqueryModal.js file will come after jquery. This solves the error in IE

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
jqueryModal.js, line 2 character 1
```

So reorder like this

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqueryModal.js"></script>
```

In popbox.css

add -ms-filter for opacity for IE. Below I have shown only one example in your CSS. Add wherever necessary. [Source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/)

```
.modalDialog {
    position: fixed;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    opacity: 0;
    /* IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    /* IE 5-7 */
     filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    color: #000066;
}
```

Comment: I made the change, but I still can not click any button on the attraction page in ie.  Also, my close function on the modal window is now not working.  I didn't change the function.  Do you see anything that it could be?

Sorry!  I really appreciate your help.  I have been going crazy googling these issues for days.  I wish I would have come here sooner :)

Comment: Make z-index to -1 and when you open a modal set the z-index to higher number. Close function works for me.